# Desvincular o perfil de todo o conteúdo apenas no meta

Tags: suporte, contas-usuário

Gostaria de saber se é possível desvincular um perfil apenas do conteúdo de minha autoria do meta, de modo que fique daquele jeito como quando alguém deleta todo o perfil de forma definitiva.

Ressalto que não estou questionando como deletar um perfil, isso eu já sei que há opção tanto de deletar apenas um perfil por rede quanto de toda a rede. A questão é apenas desvinculá-lo de conteúdos criados por mim no meta, uma vez que deletar todo o perfil resulta em desvinculação também de conteúdo do site principal.

Caso seja algo possível, gostaria de receber orientações de como proceder, ou como solicitar isso a staff da SE, caso seja apenas com eles.

Comment: E porque você iria querer fazer isso? Qual é o propósito disso? Se for por causa de alguma postagem no meta que te gerou problemas mais sérios e você tiver uma justificativa muito boa, os CMs conseguem desassociar ela da sua conta de usuário. Mas isso é só para casos muito extremos mesmo.

Comment: De acordo com o [FAQ do meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/401803), é possível desvincular seu nome de posts específicos, através do [formulário de contato](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). Mas o mesmo FAQ diz para "não abusar do serviço", então será que pedir para desassociar *todos* os posts do meta seria considerado abuso pela SE? Eu realmente não sei. De qualquer forma, o formulário de contato parece ser o caminho...

Comment: Eu to esperando algum CM confirmar isso. Porque nao queria perder tempo preenchendo aquilo pra tomar uma negativa. Se nao for possivel, pelo menos eu ja sei a resposta antes de solicitar e posso ir pelo caminho que eu tenho certeza que vai funcionar, que é apagando o perfil por inteiro. So nao queria chegar nesse extremo sem saber isso.

Comment: Talvez valha a pena falar com um mod. Há ferramentas para resolver associações problemáticas para a pessoa na vida real. Já se a idéia for excluir o perfil do Meta (ou na rede) como uma forma de protesto (e eu não estou dizendo que seja o seu caso); enquanto algo assim é potencialmente possível, sempre vale a pena esperar alguns dias para ver se a discordância é assim tão importante. Pessoalmente posso dizer que todas as vezes que me exarcebei por convicções políticas a coisa não valeu a pena.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly meus motivos não estão sendo discutidos aqui, até porque são pessoais e não são da conta de ninguém. Agora se eu não puder nem mais fazer uma pergunta no meta sem ter os motivos delas julgados, então eu peço desculpas pelo incômodo e removo a pergunta sem problemas.

Comment: Olha, não sei o que te motiva a querer uma atitude extrema dessas. Até onde sei, a sua atuação no meta tem sido extremamente positiva. Se tem uma ou outra postagem que causou problema, às vezes basta excluí-las, editá-las ou de outra forma atuar diretamente nelas e pronto, está resolvido. A sua conta não permite te identificar facilmente, afinal, Articuno é para todos os efeitos, apenas um pokémon, e não algo que possa te ligar ao seu CPF, seu endereço ou coisa assim. [continua]

Comment: [continuação] Se for uma atitude de protesto contra a SE ou coisa assim, não adianta porque mesmo que eles desassociem, eles sabem exatamente quem foi que postou, e no fim, eles não se importariam nem um pouco de qualquer forma. Se a motivação é porque alguém te encheu o saco no mundo real por causa de algo no meta, saiba que babacas há em todo lugar e se não usarem isso para te encher o saco, usarão qualquer outra coisa que puderem. Não vejo motivo para você querer algo assim, tenho a impressão que está agindo de cabeça quente e pedindo uma espécie de problema XY no meta.

Comment: Não estou de cabeça quente não, e não é uma decisão tomada ontem ou hoje.  Mas repito: não é a motivação que estou questionando aqui, isso é algo pessoal e eu não devo me explicar quanto a isso. A duvida é saber se é possivel e como. Se for beleza, se não for, apago a pergunta e vida que segue. Não vamos ficar desvirtuando querendo adivinhar a motivação, não é esse meu objetivo com a pergunta. Só quero saber da staff se é algo possivel e como solicitar.

Answer (score 5):

O que pretendes fazer pode ser conseguido simplesmente removendo o perfil Meta completamente.

O procedimento correcto é usar [o formulário de contacto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) que podes encontrar no fundo de todas as páginas, seleccionar "outro," e deixar claro que o único perfil que queres remover é o Meta, e não o principal.

Depois alguém "do nosso lado" inicia o processo de remoção de conta, e passadas 24h a conta é removida.

Comment: Já fiz o pedido via este formulário faz quase 5 dias e nada até agora.

Comment: Olha, eu fiz o pedido, recebi resposta positiva mas até hoje nada foi feito, só uma mensagem de quem meu perfil foi programado pra deleção, e já consta quase 3 dias.

Comment: É por causa do número alto de publicações associadas à conta, @ArticunoL, e do número de votos de/para a conta — faz com que seja preciso um dev dar uma olhadela antes de confirmar a remoção. vou pedir para alguém tratar disso amanhã (hoje é feriado nos EUA).